# Breakpoint disabled in configuration

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I added new project configuration called UAT and breakpoints are disabled. When I switch back to Debug configuration breakpoints are working

I compare Build properties between Debug and UAT and see no difference

[image]

Comment: What is "Debug Info" set to in "Advanced..."?

Comment: Try to Clean Solution followed by Build Solution, sometimes its the simplest things.

Comment: How do the different app/web.configs affect the.pdb's? Do the configs do anything more than transforms?

Comment: @icebat thank you that was set to none

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would check that whether it has the debugging output files in your UAT folder like the pdb file or others after you rebuild your app.

Please also view the Advanced window, and make sure that debug info=full.

[image]

If still no help, you'd better to compare the different configuration file with the .xxproj file.